# Using Hybrid Mobile application issue to display APN Localized Formatted Strings

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst, localizable.strings

I'm using Mobile First Platform 7 hybrid Mobile app, but I'm not using MFP server instead of that WebSphere Liberty profile, and I can send and received the apple push notification, but during the implementation of Localized Formatted Strings, I have this issue, when the notification arrives the alert message does not display the Localized string according to the key. and it shows "GAME_PLAY_REQUEST_FORMAT" instead of “Jenna and Frank have invited you to play Monopoly”.

Reference.. Localized Formatted Strings  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/TheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH107-SW7

The service is sending the follow structure.

```
aps =     {
        alert =         {
            "action-loc-key" = Open;
            "loc-args" =             (
                Jenna,
                Frank
            );
            "loc-key" = "GAME_PLAY_REQUEST_FORMAT";
        };
        badge = 12;
        sound = default;
    };
```

And I added the key and value `"GAME_PLAY_REQUEST_FORMAT" = "%2$@ and %1$@ have invited you to play Monopoly";` in the message.string files
[image: Localizations.bundle inside xcode project]

and I added in any of the folders located over the image fr.lproj, es.lproj, en.lproj.. etc.

I also check that my device has the proper configuration in settings -> general -> language&region -> English

I also notice that Localizable.strings is the file in native ios app and the file located in the hybrid app is messages.strings

Is there any step that I miss?

I'll appreciate any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

After researching I found the way to add Localization.string file and the language, This link help me to understand more about it https://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014, I followed the steps and then I compared whit my hybrid app then
Then I added the folders and the files in strategic position and that works.
The structure is below, [image]

[image]